# How to Dockerize an Angular Universal app with nginx

Tags: angular, docker, ubuntu, nginx

I've been attempting to use nginx to dockerize my angular universal app. When I test it with nginx, I receive a 502 bad gateway error, however  I'm able to run the SSR command to serve it on port 4000.

### This is my SSR Docker file.

```
FROM node:16.17 
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package*.json /app/
RUN npm install --force
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 4000
RUN npm run build:ssr
```

### Dockerfile for nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.23.3 
 COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 EXPOSE 80
```

### nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

### Docker ps output

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
12345fee4978   <<custom-nginx-image>>        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           ngtest
5377d412345   <<ssr-image>>    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 minutes ago   Up 43 minutes   0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp, :::4000->4000/tcp   front
```

### Docker logs for SSR container

> ```
> user@0.0.0 serve:ssr
> node dist/user/server/main.js
> ```

### Docker logs for nginx container

> ```
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
> 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
> 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
> /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.3
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-1022-aws
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:524288
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
> 2023/03/12 17:29:17 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
> 2023/03/12 17:29:43 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 124.40.247.102, server: loh, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "192.186.1.1"
> 2023/03/12 17:29:43 [warn] 28#28: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 124.40.247.102, server: loh, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "192.186.1.1"
> 2023/03/12 17:29:43 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 124.40.247.102, server: loh, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "192.186.1.1"
> 2023/03/12 17:29:43 [warn] 28#28: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 124.40.247.102, server: loh, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "192.186.1.1"
> 124.40.247.102 - - [12/Mar/2023:17:29:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.69" "-"
> ```

This didn't work both on local machine and on remote server.
I want to set up the system so that calling the IP address would run the SSR app.
Secondly, I would like to employ a reverse proxy to access my backend api, which is open on port 3000.

What is the proper procedure for doing this? Any guidelines or best practices I should adhere to here?

I would much appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i was able to solve the issue

I created network with

```
docker network create  <<NETWORK-NAME>>
```

and used this new to run the containers with `--network` flag

```
docker run --name <<ccontainer-name>> -p 4000:4000 -d --network <<NETWORK-NAME>>  <<image-name>>
```

Similarly for Nginx container as well

Then i had slightly modify my nginx.conf file as such

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```